# Método C++ para Delphi

Tags: delphi

Olá, bom dia à todos.

Por favor, gostaria de saber como ficaria esse método C++ abaixo em Delphi.

Segue:

```
bool hook(void* old_function, void* new_function)
{
  return eat_hook(old_function, new_function) && iat_hook(old_function, new_function);
}
```

Comment: Links externos não são confiáveis, substitui o link pelo código que melhor define sua dúvida.

Comment: @rubStackOverflow, No caso o trecho de código seria apenas esse acima mesmo.

Comment: E aí? ninguém sabe? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function hook(old_function: Pointer; new_function: Pointer): Boolean;
begin
   Result := eat_hook(old_function, new_function) and iat_hook(old_function, new_function);
end;
```